# migrate from Spring MVC - DAO project to Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a project in Spring MVC on Glassfish that connects to a mysql database through DAOs without any problems. Now, I'm trying to migrate the project to Spring Boot with tomcat as embedd server following [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-migration). What I have acomplished so far is this exception when I run the application:

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

This is my Hibernate configuration file which of course works fine in Spring MVC:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @ComponentScan({ "com.secretlabs.configuration" })
    @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
    public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.secretlabs.models" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
   }
```

The first thing I changed from the original MVC project was the pom.xml file. I included the spring boot dependencies and commented the spring framework dependencies to avoid conflicts in the jar versions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.secretlabs</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>myproject</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
    <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
    <jackson.databind-version>2.2.3</jackson.databind-version>
    <springsecurity.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jsr303 validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <!-- MySQL -->
    <!--
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    -->
    <!-- Joda-Time -->       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.databind-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Later, I created a Main Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

I think the problem is in the default configuration of Spring boot. How can Spring boot recognize the Hibernate configuration file?

Comment: You should not manually specify all the Spring versions; you're using very out-of-date versions that aren't compatible with Boot. Use the BOM dependency imports instead.

Comment: plus where is your datasource properties are mentoned?

Comment: @PraJazz the datasource properties are under src/main/resources. These are the exact same properties of the Spring MVC project.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks, I will take a look to BOM dependency imports. However in the pom, the spring framework dependencies are commented, I'm only using the dependencies from spring-boot.

Comment: Ah, the syntax highlighting is missing the comments. You're providing a `dataSource` bean, which should be sufficient--are you sure that your configuration class is getting loaded at all? You might also take this opportunity to cut out most or all of that configuration and go with the Boot configuration properties setup.

Answer (score 1):

Try following things might help:

- Use newer/latest version of Spring Boot.
- Try with default properties file `application.properties`.
- Make sure you have `mysql-connector` and `hibernate/data-jpa` `starters/dependency` in your `pom.xml`.

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional: to use JPA 2.1 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```